# Hive rlike matching word boundary

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, word-boundary, rlike

I am new to Hive regex matching and struggling to find the right pattern for matching word boundaries:

```
haystack RLIKE concat('(?i)\b', 'needle', '\b')
```

doesn't return anything.

Sample values which I have in DB:

```
haystack
---------
needless to say
this is a needle
so many (needle)
these are needles
```

When I use `haystack RLIKE concat('(?i)', 'needle')`, it returns me all the rows but I am actually looking for `this is a needle`.

Comment: are you looking for a logic like - i should come first and then needle? Then you can use below logic -  `where  instr(col,'i') >0 AND instr(col,'needle') >0 AND instr(col,'i') < instr(col,'needle') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive use two backslashes: `\\b`

Demo:

```
with mytable as (
select stack(4,
'needless to say',
'this is a needle',
'so many (needle)',
'these are needles'
) as haystack
)

select haystack, haystack rlike concat('(?i)\\b', 'needle', '\\b') from mytable;
```

Result:

```
haystack             _c1
needless to say      false
this is a needle     true
so many (needle)     true
these are needles    false
```

Note that `so many (needle)` is also matched because `(` and `)` are not word characters.